# SSRS display 2 different details

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to create an ssrs report where the parent grouping has 2 different sets of details,  I can't seem to figure out how to display the unique details below the parent row

example:

```
table1
master
master1
master2

table2
master,  hand
master1, hand1
master1, hand2
master2, hand1
master2, hand2

table3
master, foot
master1, foot1
master1, foot2
master2, foot1
master2, foot2
```

my sql query is as follows

```
select t1.master, t2.hand, t3.foot
from table1 t1 
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.master = t2.master
left outer join table2 t3 on t1.master = t3.master
```

I want the ssrs report output to be

```
master1
hand1
hand2
foot1
foot2

master2
hand1
hand2
foot1
foot2
```

so far I've been able to get

```
master1
hand1
hand2
master2
hand1
hand2
```

but as soon as I try to add another row to display foot it links to the hand not master so it appears like this

```
master1
hand1
foot1
hand1
foot2
hand2
foot1
hand2
foot2

master2
hand1
foot1
hand1
foot2
hand2
foot1
hand2
foot2
```

if i add another row outside the grouping it only shows the first row from table3

```
master1
hand1
hand2
foot1

master2
hand1
hand2
foot1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data:

[image]

Starting with a `master` group and child group based on `hand`:

[image]

add an **adjacent group** to the `hand` group, but group on `foot` this time:

[image]

[image]

The tablix looks something like this now:

[image]

Which gives the required results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Best idea is to change the structure of your data. Rather than joining all three tables, do two separate queries (1 for `t2` and 1 for `t3`) and union them together, then you get your data in rows and it's much easier to group. You'll need to sort the details group by `tableName`

```
select t1.id, t2.detail, 't2' tableName from (
select 'master' id union
select 'master1' id union
select 'master2' id) t1
left outer join
(
select 'master' id,  'hand' detail union
select 'master1' id, 'hand1' detail union
select 'master1' id, 'hand2' detail union
select 'master2' id, 'hand1' detail union
select 'master2' id, 'hand2' detail )t2
on t1.id = t2.id

UNION

select t1.id, t3.detail, 't3' tableName from (
select 'master' id union
select 'master1' id union
select 'master2' id) t1
left outer join
(
select 'master' id, 'foot' detail union
select 'master1' id, 'foot1' detail union
select 'master1' id, 'foot2' detail union
select 'master2' id, 'foot1' detail union
select 'master2' id, 'foot2' detail)t3
on t1.id = t3.id
```

[image: groupingExample2]

Result is

[image: Grouping result]

Comment: Does that first option work? Based on the original query, there is no natural hand/foot hierarchy so I would think adjacent groups are required. What grouping would you suggest? That said, the best option here is really to change the query to allow a more natural report, as you've described, so +1 for that!

Comment: @IanPreston I think you're right.. as there is more than one detail row for the hand/foot the first option wouldn't have worked. My first option was to change the query though, the other grouping was an after thought because I thought I'd missed an easy trick.